# Why does saving not save and instead open up a new notebook?

Tags: notebooks, save

I have been working on a notebook and when trying to save (using Ctrl+S or 'File' and 'Save'), the notebook does not save and instead a new blank notebook opens up. Doing 'File' and 'Save As' does nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The "bugs" tag is reserved for questions where the problem has been vetted by this community and the observed behavior is confirmed to be a bug. Please do not use this tag for new questions.

Comment: Did you change any key bindings or keyboard shortcuts? Have you tried IT's oldest trick, i.e. restarting MMA or your computer as well? This is almost certainly local to your machine and may be impossible for us to diagnose.

Comment: Are other shortcuts mixed up as well? I experienced this after a random time of intensive use. Couple of times but it was not related to anything specific. Does it persist after you restart MMA?

Comment: I want to avoid restarting because I would lose what I'm working on. How do I find whether I've changed any key bindings or keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @Chris Execute `NotebookSave[]` in the notebook you want to save. You should be prompted for a file name to save to if the file has no name. Alternatively, you can use `NotebookSave[EvaluationNotebook[], "filenameToSaveTo.nb"]`. Once you have a safe copy, restart everything and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately Mathematica stopped responding when I tried this :( Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: More than once, I have seen this situation where apparently the mappings from the invoked front end command to what actually happens is altered. Unfortunately I have not found a way to reproduce it.